# Suddenly webcam of my x300 is not working

Tags: 11.04, webcam, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on my Thinkpad x300. My webcam was working fine with skype or gmail video. Suddenly it is stopped working. Now, no LED green light either with skype or gmail video call. I also installed cheese and cheese is reporting that "no camera found". And skype is unable to detect the webcam (checked in the options). I am not sure whether it is a hardware problem or because of one of recent Ubuntu updates. Please see the information of machine below and help me to fix this. I also did not observe any errors messages related to this in the output of dmesg.

```
$uname -a 
Linux my-thinkpad 2.6.38-13-generic-pae #54-Ubuntu SMP Tue
Jan 3 15:11:05 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 0c)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HBM (ICH8M-E) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection (rev 61)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have installed *libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2* and restarted the machine. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation on the developer site of the uvc driver (http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#documentation) I upgraded the userspace UVC tools (uvcdynctrl) via apt-get, i.e.

sudo apt-get install uvcdynctrl

After that the camera started working again (without a reboot).